# cannot set environmental variable in conda

Tags: conda

I'm trying to set up an environmental variable in conda, but when I do `set GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"` and then `echo $GIT_SSH_COMMAND` I get nothing. If I do `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"` I get an error saying that `The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`. In other words, I can't set environment variables in conda.

How can I solve this?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`...as the name of a cmdlet`" suggests a Powershell session.

You would need, as [seen here](https://www.educba.com/set-variable-in-powershell/):

```
$env:GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'
```

Or, in a Conda session, see "[Setting environment variables](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables)"

```
conda env config vars set GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'
```

Comment: The first part of your answer was extremely helpful. I edited my question and your answer to reflect this. I will open a new question regarding the `ssh` problem. Thanks